# How to implement google Analytics API to get reports Of my existing Google Analytics Account?

Tags: javascript, java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Actually i already have google analytics account from where i can able to see all the tracking information of my website.

So how can i create or map existing google analytics account with google analytics API in developer console to implement my rest service to get tracking information.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I reckon the Google Analytics API docs are pretty informative, when you read them: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: Thanks for your response . Do i need to create a new project in api console to get my existing google analytics account information?@DavidM.

Comment: Yes you need to create a project in API Console: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization

Comment: After creating project in API console . How i can i get the information of my existing google analytics account in my new created project in API console .@DavidM.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: are you working with java or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics API is authenticated using OAuth2, which means that your application must get an authorization token from a user with access to your Google Analytics account before interacting with the API.

There are SDKs for most major development platforms available.

The OAuth2 flow is roughly the following:

- Your app redirects your user to Google's UI for letting them grant your app permission to use the API on their behalf. *Important:* you'll probably need to request [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) to get a token that can be refreshed when it expires so that your user doesn't have to always provide auth credentials.
- When the user has granted the app, the user's browser is redirected to your application with a token
- Your app should store that token and use the token for all interactions with the API.

NOTE: In addition to the above, you must first register your application to the Google API console to obtain an API key to identify your application.

NOTE 2: You can read about offline access and refresh tokens [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline). Most libraries provided by Google will handle refreshing the tokens for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yeah I haven't registered my application in API console.But i have google analytics account . Right now what i need to do to register my existing analytics account in API console to get an authorization token.

Comment: i have created a project in developer console . when i tried to fetch my analytic record i got this errors  "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"

Comment: Actually since this seems to be a server side application instead of something a client logs into a service account might be more appropriate. A service account does not need to follow the OAuth flow- you get your credentials as a json file and your application can request authentication without user interaction (as long as the email address of your service account is added to the GA account).

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer.Yes I have configured my service account id in GA account mail id.Its working excellent.@EikePierstorff